# Firefox not pasting with Ctrl-v inside textarea

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Firefox (95.0.2) on a MacOS (Big Sur 11.6.2) and changed the [Ui.key.generalAccessKey](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Ui.key.generalAccessKey) (to 17 for `Ctrl`) to use `Ctrl` instead of `Command` to support copy/paste a la windows (i.e. `ctrl-c` to copy, `ctrl-v` to paste).

All seems to work fine for the most part except I am not able to use `ctrl-v` to paste into textarea boxes on what seems to be certain sites (though pasting into normal input boxes, the URL bar, etc works fine). Firefox just flashes the "Edit" option on the menu bar as if to suggest I should invoke "Edit -> Paste" to paste - and then the cursor seems to jump from where editing was happening to the end of the textarea. I suspect some Javascript editing control at play perhaps though I can't be sure.

For example, this happens in gmail, azure devops, [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/). This does not happen here on [Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com/questions/ask), [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/107394), [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea).

It's a tad bit annoying and a productivity dip finding that you can `ctrl-v` on some sites but on others you now have to reach for the mouse to right click to paste as `Command-v` no longer works. Any tips to get to the bottom of this would be appreciated.

Comment: Revert it all to defaults. Learn how to use it. You're fighting a losing battle because Cmd/v is universal on Mac, yet there are many undocumented emacs-style shortcuts that use Ctrl/key. Then there are sites like this one which use Ctrl/key to format markdown. All in all you're just making a rod for your own back.

Comment: @Tetsujin - not an option. Mostly all of the applications I use - MS Teams, Terminals, Editors - all use `ctrl-c/ctrl-v` - I need consistency.

Answer (score 3):

That's probably blocked by the website for certain text boxes (for example the email verification box). Try Don't Fuck With Paste:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/don-t-fuck-with-paste/

You'll have to add the website you want this to work on by clicking on the extension icon, then and clicking **'add pattern'** (the default regex string that the plugin suggests should normally work):

[image]

Comment: don't know about that extension, but the gist is correct, web developers can design pages to tell the browser not to allow copy/paste on elements like text inputs. you can sometimes tell the browser to ignore those restrictions, but that is not without its flaws.

Comment: I assume there are different ways to achieve this effect. This extension disables most of them, but not all.

Comment: I tried this extension but it hasn't helped. :/

Comment: Pity :( curious about other solutions as well, I now recall there is one website I use that doesn't allow copypasting text input, even with the above plugin...

Comment: Just realised the functionality of this extension now works from a standard 'whitelist all' rather than the original 'blacklist all', meaning you have to add urls in order to make it work. I'll update my post.

Comment: This extension works for me. Here's what makes users ask this question - some developers are preventing pasting into text boxes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320069/how-to-prevent-user-pasting-text-in-a-textbox